# Umuly short link creating service problem

Tags: hyperlink, short

when i do a post https://umuly.com/api/url with body :  `{ "RedirectUrl": "www.youtube.com"}`

i get this message:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "statusText": "Value cannot be . (Parameter 'uriString')",
    "item": ,
    "itemCount": 0,
    "skipCount": 0,
    "requestDate": "2020-09-10T02:09:37.2912502-07:00",
    "responseDate": "2020-09-10T02:09:37.2933547-07:00"
}
,undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting it because the protocol is not written.
You must write **http:// or https://** at the beginning of the domain name

```
{ "RedirectUrl": "https://www.youtube.com"}
```